# I am trying to make A JS bot who sends images

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const PREFIX = "!";

client.on("message", (message) => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case "kanye":
      message.channel.send('kanye kisses kanye; colorized')
      const attachment = new attachment('./kanyek.jpeg')
      console.log('kanye succesfully scoopity poopity')

      break;
  }
});
```

In the terminal, I get the error, ReferenceError: Cannot access 'attachment' before initialization. Please advise.

Comment: name attachment something different than the attachment constructor that you are using. const myAttachment = new attachment('./kanyek.jpeg')

Answer (score 0):

In

```js
      const attachment = new attachment('./kanyek.jpeg')
```

attachement has the exact same name as the attachment constructor. It's like saying

```js
let ab = ab + 1
```

makes no sence. So changes attachment to something else

```js
const attach = new Attachment('./kanyek.jpeg')
```